# How to generate a XML without a namespace with the latest version of org.clojure/data.xml

Tags: xml, clojure

When generating a XML with [org.clojure/data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml) with the latest stable version 0.0.8, we get a non-namespaced XML back. When generating a XML with the latest preview release 0.2.0-alpha6, it generates a prefixed XML.

According to the [libraries documentation](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml#namespace-support), namespace support is a new feature. However, how is possible to generate a XML without a namespace? For some XMLs, like Atom, this is a requirement for a valid XML.

Here's the code that works on both versions:

```clj
(xml/emit-str
 (xml/sexp-as-element
  [:feed {:xmlns "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}]))
```

In stable, it generates:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"/>"
```

In the preview release, it generates:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"/>"
```

Notice the auto-generated `:a` namespace prefix in the latter.

---

Update: alex-miller proposed a solution to the above problem in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615916/252585

I would very much like to accept this answer, because it seems to solve what I've asked. However, for the sake of getting a valid Atom feed, it pushes the problem further down the line. I've looked at the documentation with the new information on using an URI alias, but haven't been successful in generating one. Here's the resulting new problem with the proposed approach:

The stable version of clojure.data.xml produces:

```clj
(xml/emit-str
 (xml/sexp-as-element
  [:feed {:xmlns "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
   [:title "Some site title"]]))

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"><title>Some site title</title></feed>"
```

The latest version with the new approach produces:

```clj
(xml/emit-str 
  (xml/sexp-as-element 
   [::atom/feed {:xmlns "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}
    [:title "Some site title"]]))

=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"><title xmlns=\"\" xmlns:a=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">Some site title</title></feed>"
```

This syntax, will again be rejected by Atom validators and feed readers. Here is an example: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/505721/97803188-bbdd5600-1c48-11eb-986a-14d441344e70.png

Comment: What makes you think Atom requires non-namespaced XML? It would be surprising for an XML format to require non-spec-compliant XML parsers. https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rfc4287.html#namespace.and.version looks like it understands namespaces just fine.

Comment: @amalloy The rationale is that the documentation that you're linking to is stale and not even the w3.org validator is adhering to it. In fact, it will show such feeds as invalid. If it wouldn't, that would have saved me quite some time. A great many feed readers will reject your feed without even trying, because it's invalid (for example Thunderbird, FreshRSS, Miniflux, etc). Others will not validate and just work, making this a hard to even see bug. You can find screenshots and examples here: https://github.com/hashobject/perun/pull/251

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can get what you want like this using uri aliases:

```
(require '[clojure.data.xml :as xml])

;; declare a uri alias in this namespace
(xml/alias-uri 'atom "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

;; use the alias as tag prefix, but also declare at the root as default
(xml/emit-str 
  (xml/sexp-as-element 
    [::atom/feed {:xmlns "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"}]))

;; emitted string:
;; "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><feed xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"/>"
```

Comment: Mister Miller, thank you very much for answering. It's an honor!

I would very much like to accept this answer, because it seems to solve what I've asked. At least, I've voted it up(; However, for the sake of getting a valid Atom feed, it pushes the problem further down the line. I have updated the question above.

Thank you, again, it's much appreciated 

Comment: @AlainM.Lafon You will have to keep using the qualified keywords throughout. The same approach is used for example in Leiningen [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/2.9.4/src/leiningen/pom.clj#L346-L387).

Comment: @gtls You are absolutely right. I just did and confirm that generated Atom feeds with the new version of clojure.data.xml and syntax now pass the W3org validator just as the old version did. Thank you for helping out, it's much appreciated! 

One Clojure based FOSS static site generator more running on the latest release, now(;